# python-jira login without password? Any possible way to create encrypted token and use in lieu password?

Tags: python-jira

Below is python test code to login `jira` using username and password and it works fine.

```
from jira import JIRA

jira = JIRA('http://xxx')
jira = JIRA(basic_auth=('username','password'),options={'server': 'http://xxx'})

issue = jira.issue('XXXX-762')

print "For task", issue,", summary is-", issue.fields.summary
```

Now I require to log in `jira` without using password.
can anyone help?

Aim of this is to hide the password in general script and also make the script independent of jira password expiry.

Jira version used: JIRA v7.5.2

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting to obfuscate the password inside of the script? If so, this is not really a JIRA/python problem. The easiest is to base64 encode the password beforehand and then just use:

```
jira = JIRA(basic_auth=('username',base64.b64decode("<encrypted_password")),options={'server': 'http://xxx'})
```

This, of course, doesn't fully protect you but at least makes it much less obvious.

Comment: Base64 is no encryption scheme. Is is an Encoding scheme. Therefore there is no encrypted password. Its an encoded password.

Comment: It also doesn't answer the question. The question asked about how to do it **without** using a password.

Comment: The op said absolutely nothing about encrypting...and neither did I. And the op also said nothing about how to do it without a password...they said they didn't want the password to show up in the script. I was just offering a way where the password was not clearly in the script (and saying it doesn't protect them).

Answer (score 0):

You can work with your Jira administrator to set up OAuth for authentication for your script instead of basic auth, which would eliminate the need for a password. It requires considerable setup to get it working, but would ultimately serve your needs.

Here is an overview from Atlassian on how the overall process works: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-oauth-authentication/

Here is a link to the Atlassian repository for examples on setting up OAuth including an example in Python: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/atlassian-oauth-examples/overview

Answer (score 0):

I just set the password in an environment variable and have the script read it.

```
from jira import JIRA

jira_user = os.environ.get("JIRA_USERNAME", None)
jira_password = os.environ.get("JIRA_PASSWORD", None)
jira_server = {'server': "https://jiraserver.url"}
jira = JIRA(options=jira_server, basic_auth=(jira_user, jira_password))
```